# organize subsets after splitting a vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm new to R and I'm trying to program more effectively.
I have different vectors and I split each of them into subsets:

```
vector_a <- 1:10000
nb_of_subsets <- 100
generate_subsets <- split(vector_a, ceiling(seq_along(vector_a)/nb_of_subsets))


vector_b <- 1:9000
nb_of_subsets <- 100
generate_subsets <- split(vector_b, ceiling(seq_along(vector_b)/nb_of_subsets))
```

Splitting works well, but I also would like to z-normalize each subset.
So it should be something like this for each subset:

```
norm_Sub1<-(generate_subsets$`1`-mean(generate_subsets$`1`))/sd(generate_subsets$`1`)
```

Any suggestions how to handle (and rename) subsets effectively? I do not want to writh tons of code...

Thank you very much!

Mel

Comment: why you are naming the same `generate_subsets` for both

Comment: check the `lapply()`/`apply()` concept. In your case `by()` would also be an option.

Comment: elegant method to split such an vector into equal parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the output is a `list`, we can loop over the `list` with `lapply` and then apply the normalization function.

```
normList <- lapply(generate_subsets, function(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x))
```